# How to print values in memoization method-Dynamic pragraming

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming, memoization

I know for a problem that can be solved using DP, can be solved by either tabulation(bottom-up) approach or memoization(top-down) approach. personally i find memoization is easy and even efficient approach(analysis required just to get recursive formula,once recursive formula is obtained, a brute-force recursive method can easily be converted to store sub-problem's result and reuse it.) The only problem that i am facing in this approach is, i am not able to construct actual result from the table which i filled on demand.
For example, in [Matrix Product Parenthesization problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-8-matrix-chain-multiplication/) ( to decide in which order to perform the multiplications on Matrices so that cost of multiplication is minimum) i am able to calculate minimum cost not not able to generate order in algo.

For example, suppose A is a 10 × 30 matrix, B is a 30 × 5 matrix, and C is a 5 × 60 matrix. Then,

```
(AB)C = (10×30×5) + (10×5×60) = 1500 + 3000 = 4500 operations
A(BC) = (30×5×60) + (10×30×60) = 9000 + 18000 = 27000 operations.
```

here  i am able to get min-cost as 27000 but unable to get order which is A(BC).

I used this. Suppose F[i, j] represents least number of multiplication needed to multiply Ai.....Aj and an array p[] is given which represents the chain of matrices such that the ith matrix Ai is of dimension p[i-1] x p[i]. So

> ```
>                     0                 if i=j
>      F[i,j]=
>                    min(F[i,k] + F[k+1,j] +P_i-1 * P_k * P_j   where k∈[i,j)
> ```

Below is the implementation that i have created.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 4
int lookup[MAX][MAX];

int MatrixChainOrder(int p[], int i, int j)
{
    if(i==j) return 0;
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int k, count;

    if(lookup[i][j]==0){
        // recursively calculate count of multiplcations and return the minimum count
        for (k = i; k<j; k++) {
            int gmin=0;
            if(lookup[i][k]==0)
                lookup[i][k]=MatrixChainOrder(p, i, k);

            if(lookup[k+1][j]==0)
                lookup[k+1][j]=MatrixChainOrder(p, k+1, j);

            count = lookup[i][k] + lookup[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];
            if (count < min){
                min = count;
```

> ```
>               printf("\n****%d  ",k); // i think something has be done here to represent the correct answer ((AB)C)D  where first mat is represented by  A second by B and so on.
> ```

```
            }

        }
        lookup[i][j] = min;
    }

    return lookup[i][j];
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2,3,6,4,5};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    memset(lookup, 0, sizeof(lookup));
    int width =10;

    printf("Minimum number of multiplications is %d ", MatrixChainOrder(arr, 1, n-1));
    printf("\n  ---->");
    for(int l=0;l<MAX;++l)
    printf(" %*d ",width,l);
    printf("\n");
    for(int z=0;z<MAX;z++){
        printf("\n  %d--->",z);
    for(int x=0;x<MAX;x++)
    printf(" %*d ",width,lookup[z][x]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know using tabulation approach printing the solution is much easy but i want to  do it in memoization technique.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code correctly computes the minimum number of multiplications, but you're struggling to display the optimal chain of matrix multiplications.

There's two possibilities:

1. When you compute the table, you can store the best index found in another memoization array.
2. You can recompute the optimal splitting points from the results in the memoization array.

The first would involve creating the split points in a separate array:

```
int lookup_splits[MAX][MAX];
```

And then updating it inside your `MatrixChainOrder` function:

```
    ...
    if (count < min) {
        min = count;
        lookup_splits[i][j] = k;   
    }
```

You can then generate the multiplication chain recursively like this:

```
void print_mult_chain(int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) {
        putchar('A' + i - 1);
        return;
    }
    putchar('(');
    print_mult_chain(i, lookup_splits[i][j]);
    print_mult_chain(lookup_splits[i][j] + 1, j);
    putchar(')');
}
```

You can call the function with `print_mult_chain(1, n - 1)` from `main`.

The second possibility is that you don't cache `lookup_splits` and recompute it as necessary.

```
int get_lookup_splits(int p[], int i, int j) {
    int best = INT_MAX;
    int k_best;
    for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
        int count = lookup[i][k] + lookup[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];
        if (count < best) {
            best = count;
            k_best = k;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

This is essentially the same computation you did inside `MatrixChainOrder`, so if you go with this solution you should factor the code appropriately to avoid having two copies.

With this function, you can adapt `print_mult_chain` above to use it rather than the `lookup_splits` array. (You'll need to pass the `p` array in).

[None of this code is tested, so you may need to edit the answer to fix bugs].

Comment: First one i got and its working correctly but how its being done in second case?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking about the second case. You don't know how it works, or you don't know how to write `print_mult_chain` using the new function?

Comment: I didnt get what you want to achieve in second fn.You're not memoizing k in additional array.From where the fn get_lookup_splits will be called,it's very similar to the code i used for lookup filling.

Comment: It can replace accesses to the `lookup_splits` array when you're printing the chain. See: https://gist.github.com/paulhankin/6c43ab65236b52dce643d92f19fabdbf . Each call is O(n), so it makes printing the chain O(n^2), but `MatrixChainOrder` was already O(n^2) [both in the worst case].